# Let $X$ be a topological space and $\pi:\mathbb R^2\to X$ a covering map.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. Suppose $\pi:\mathbb R^2\setminus B\to X\setminus K$ is a homeomorphism. Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Conclusions I can make now are as follows:

-The fundamental group is a topological invariant so this means $\pi_1(\mathbb R^2\setminus B)\cong \pi_1(X\setminus K)$

-$S_1$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$ $\Rightarrow$ $\pi_1(\mathbb R^2\setminus B)\cong \pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$

-Since $\mathbb R^2$ is simply connected, each fiber of $\pi$ has the same cardinality as the fundamental group of $X$.

It should be enough to show that $X$ is simply connected, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that the inverse image of every point has at least two elements. At least one of these must lie in the unit ball. Choose a countable sequence that has no limit points in $X\setminus K$. Looking at the preimages in $B$ and the "evenly covered" property gives a contradiction.

Comment: How do we know such a countable sequence with no limit points exist in $X\setminus K$?

Comment: Well it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$, where it is easy to find such a sequence that goes out to infinity.

Comment: Ok I see that now. I am still having trouble reaching a contradiction. Let $\{y_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be a countable sequence that has no limit points in $X\setminus K$. By assumption, $|\pi^{-1}(\{y_i\})|>1$. Only one preimage of $y_i$ can lie in $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$ due to the homeomorphism. So all other preimages must lie in $B$.

Comment: And since $B$ is compact, those preimages must have a limit point in $B$.

Comment: The image of the limit point $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ that is evenly covered by $pi$.  So $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is a union of disjoint open set $V_i\subseteq \mathbb R^2$. So $p$ must lie in a single $V_k$. Since $p$ is a limit point, $V_k$ must contain another element of $B$. If the element has the same image as $p$ then we will contradict the evenly covered condition, but I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Exactly. If you have a discrete countable set $S$ and take its preimage under a covering transformation it is still discrete. Find disjoint evenly covered neighborhoods of the points of $S$. Then each point in the preimage of $s\in S$ has a disjoint open neighborhood homeomorphic to the chosen neighborhood of $s$.

Comment: Okay I think I see it. So since $p$ is a limit point$V_k$ $\textit{must} $ contain another preimage of $y_i$.

Comment: Indeed.${{}{}}$